# Change to libertine font except in certain parts?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, environments, libertine

I am producing my LaTeX document using `pdflatex`. If I want to switch my entire document to a libertine font I use :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\texttt{Hello, this is a test !}
\begin{lstlisting}
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Two questions (using pdflatex) :

- How to switch all fonts to libertine except `\ttfamily`
- How to switch all fonts to libertine (including `\ttfamily`) except in all listings ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For libertine/biolinum except `\ttfamily`:

```
\usepackage[tt=false] {libertine}
```

For always libertine except listings which uses in this example Bera Mono:

```
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont\small}
```

Answer (score 5):

To switch all fonts to libertine except `\ttfamily`, use the `tt=false` option to the libertine package.  (I don't know how to set the default font for listings.)